# How do I write this as non-LINQ code?

Tags: c#, linq, excel

I found some example of how to read the XML from an Excel spreadsheet [>> HERE <<](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/reading-and-writing-excel-2007-or-excel-2010-c-part-v-full-source-reading), and I am trying to get the code to work for me. I have to write a routine that takes the data from 4 of the 15 sheets in the workbook, and use that data to populate our database. Anyway....

This code is throwing an `InvalidOperationException` exception every time I attempt to query my Excel spreadsheet:

```
static XElement GetWorksheet(string sheetName, PackagePartCollection allParts) {
  XElement element = null;
  try {
    PackagePart worksheetPart = (from part in allParts
                                 where part.Uri.OriginalString.Equals(String.Format("/xl/worksheets/{0}.xml", sheetName))
                                 select part).Single();
    element = XElement.Load(XmlReader.Create(worksheetPart.GetStream()));
  } catch (Exception err) { // catches InvalidOperationException
    Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
  }
  return element;
}
```

The specific error is, *"Sequence contains no elements"*

I'm really not sure how to go about debugging it, because I'm not sure what the code is trying to do.

Could someone help me write it in Standard" C# before I try to implement the fancy LINQ expression? (that **is** LINQ, right?)

**[Solved]**

Using the snippet provided by [JeffN825](https://stackoverflow.com/users/326518/jeffn825), I was able to create this:

```
static XElement GetWorksheet(string sheetName, PackagePartCollection allParts) {
  string xmlCompare = string.Format("/xl/worksheets/{0}.xml", sheetName);
  foreach (PackagePart part in allParts) {
    string original = part.Uri.OriginalString;
    if (original == xmlCompare) {
      XElement element = XElement.Load(XmlReader.Create(part.GetStream()));
      return element;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It turns out that even though my sheet names in Excel are "HV", "M2", "CB" and "CC", I still have to specify them as "sheet2", "sheet3", "sheet4" and "sheet5".

I had to step through 161 `PackagePart` objects to see this.

LINQ is just so damn efficient that it can be hard to debug when there are problems.

Comment: The error is a result of calling `Single()` on a empty sequence. In this case, there is no part with a Uri that matches the `sheetName` you're passing in. Have you confirmed that this sheet exists?

Comment: `SingleOrDefault()` will avoid throwing the error, but will set worksheetPart to `null`.

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Single()`. This shall return null in case there are no eligible elements.

Comment: The worksheet does exist (I manually provide the text for the sheet name), but I do not call them in order of appearance. The first sheet is called `Code`, and I skip over that.

Comment: @jp2code You should manually inspect `allParts` to see what the parts actually look like; it's possible the `Uri` isn't in the correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Single()` is what's throwing the exception. Either your query is returning no items  or it's returning > 1 item. If you're not sure of the number of items you're expecting, you should be using `FirstOrDefault()` which will return the first match or null if no matches are found.

The non-LINQ equivalent is something like this

```
PackagePart worksheetPart = null
foreach(var part in allParts)
{
   if (part.Uri.OriginalString.Equals(String.Format("/xl/worksheets/{0}.xml", sheetName))))
   {
       if (part != null) throw new InvalidOperationException(); // > 1 match
       worksheetPart = part;
   }
}
if (part == null) throw new InvalidOperationException(); // no match
```

Answer (score 2):

It's basically doing this.

```
PackagePart worksheetPart;

foreach(PackagePart part in allParts)
{
    if(part.Uri.OriginalString.Equals(String.Format("/xl/worksheets/{0}.xml", sheetName)))
    { 
        worksheetPart = part;
        break;
    }
}
```

In your version, try replacing .Single() with .FirstOrDefault().

It's failing because there is no match.

Comment: How would I extract the `XElement` out of that `worksheetPart`?

Answer (score 2):

```
(from part in allParts
  where part.Uri.OriginalString.Equals(String.Format("/xl/worksheets/{0}.xml", sheetName))
  select part).Single();
```

Your error is in `Single()`. If your query has no values in it, Single() throws that exception. What you should use instead is `SingleOrDefault()`, which will return `null` if there's no values from the query.

Comment: He should be figuring out *why the sequence has no elements*, not how to ignore a very relevant error message.

Comment: Well yes, but we can't help him with that based on what he posted so far. He seemed confused by the exception, and we CAN help him go from an exception to a no-results case he can understand and deal with. So I think its valid.

Comment: Actually, I'm confused by the LINQ and Excel's XML.